# How to avoid refresh in AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, cgi

I have a client and a server written in CGI(c++), as JS model is like to ask something from server, there is no mechanism for server to send async message. So this means the client needs to poll server periodically?

I read BOSH protocol, it says to achieve the async for http, a web page can issue several HTTP request, but the server will hold until it has any async events to the client. But I don't know how long the server can hold the connection if there is no data.

How to resolve this problem, i think it should be resolved well already :)

Bin

BOSH: http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0206.html